# My Countdown Timer is Stuck and Game doesn't stop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a Countdown timer for when my player buys a second life for 3 seconds before the game starts playing again. I'm not sure what I need to fix below to make it work. Currently, all the UIs pop up when it is supposed to and the countdown timer text does pop up too, but the game continues and the timer is stuck at 3.

```
public static bool GameOver = false;
public static bool CountDown = false;

public GameObject deathMenuUI;
public GameObject countDownUI;

public int timeLeft = 3;
public Text countDownText;

public float slowness = 10f;

public void Start()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", 0);
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
}

public void EndGame()
{
    StartCoroutine(DeathScreen());
}
//on death, slow time for one second and open deathscreen UI
IEnumerator DeathScreen()
{
    Time.timeScale = 1f / slowness;
    Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.fixedDeltaTime / slowness;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f / slowness);

    Time.timeScale = 1f;
    Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.fixedDeltaTime * slowness;

    deathMenuUI.SetActive(true);
    Time.timeScale = 0f;
    GameOver = true;
}
//if game is continued, close deathUI and start timer
public void continueGame()
{
    deathMenuUI.SetActive(false);
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
    GameOver = false;
    StartCoroutine(LoseTime());
}
private void Update()
{
    countDownText.text = ("" + timeLeft);
    if (timeLeft <= 0)
    {
        StopCoroutine(LoseTime());
    }
}
IEnumerator LoseTime()
{
    while (true)
    {
        countDownUI.SetActive(true);
        CountDown = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        timeLeft--;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your Deathscreen only waits for 100ms and then it's GameOver... is that intentional?

Comment: It's actually 1 second. It creates a bullet time effect on death that slows time :)

Comment: Try putting Debug.Log inside your IEnumerator LoseTime() and see if the coroutine actually has been triggered or not

Comment: And I don't see you reset the `timeLeft` variable anywhere in your code which you should do inside your `continueGame()` function so that when you call `continueGame()` after the first time your countdown won't start from numbers that are less than or equal to 0 instead of 3 like you wanted

Comment: AH, didn't know that WaitForSeconds is manipulated by Time.scale. Thats nice to know :) . But then i would too suspect like Visal Chhourm does, that the Coroutine isn't actually called.

Comment: @VisalChhourm The continueGame() can only be called once unless the scene is reloaded. Should I still reset the timeLeft variable? Also, I found out that the code above actually does count down. However, the game still plays and if I include a Time.timescale = 0f; the timer stops also. Do you know a fix for this?

Comment: If you want to use waitForSeconds and TimeScale 0 together, you should use," yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(time);". WaitForSecondsRealtime does not depend on timeScale, its depends on computer's clock.

Comment: If want it to be able to call only once unless the scene reload the you don't need to reset it. And if you want to set the timescale = 0 and call the coroutine then you need to replace `WaitForSeconds` with `WaitForSecondsRealtime` like @Prodian suggested. Here is the doc link https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html

Comment: So I was able to use WaitForSecondsRealtime to pause the game for 3 seconds, but the countdownUI still stops with it. Is there a way to have that count down while the rest of the game is paused?

Comment: @BrendonSon I don't quite get your question. Base on my understanding, you want to show the `countdownUI` along with the `countdownText` counting down 3 seconds while the game is still paused and then when the countdown is over then you want your `countdownUI` to disappear as well? Is that what you want right?

Comment: @VisalChhourm yes, that is exaclty what I want, but I can't seem to get all aspects of that working at the same time :( I can either get the timer going or pause the game. not both haha :/

Comment: @BrendonSon I posted my answer below. It contains the codes that I modified with the comments that should help you solve the problem. Hope that can solve your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you set `Time.timeScale = 0` to pause your game then you need to use `WaitForSecondsRealtime` instead of `WaitForSeconds` (just like @Prodian suggested in comment section) because `WaitForSecondsRealtime` use unscaled time which remain unaffected no matter what value you set `Time.timeScale` to.

I've made some modification on your codes here:

```
//if game is continued, close deathUI and start timer
public void continueGame()
{
    // Add this line to prevent accident like double click... which will start multiple coroutine and cause unexpected result
    if (CountDown) return;
    CountDown = true;
    deathMenuUI.SetActive(false);
    // Since you want your game to still being paused for 3 seconds before resuming
    Time.timeScale = 0;
    StartCoroutine(LoseTime());
}

private void AfterCountdownFinished()
{
    // important. You must set your Time.timeScale back to its default value
    // because even if you reload your scene the timeScale remain the same which can cause you to encounter freeze error which you might spend time to search for the problem

    Time.timeScale = 1;
    GameOver = CountDown = false;
    countDownUI.SetActive(false);
    // You want to write your restart/continue logic here
    // Example:
    // reload the level
    // SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
}

IEnumerator LoseTime()
{
    // I forgot this part (which you pointed out)
    countDownUI.SetActive(true);
    // Here is how you can improve performance

    // It seems you can't create and reuse it like WaitForSeconds
    // var delay = new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
    // Set this the text here so it will display (3 in your case) for 1 second before start decreasing
    countDownText.text = timeLeft.ToString();

    // If your level will restart after the countdown ends then you don't need to create another variable like below. You can just use timeLeft directly
    int time = timeLeft;
    while (time > 0)
    {
        // Edited here
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
        time--;
        // Here you don't set your UI text every frame in the update but you only set it only when there is change on timeLeft
        countDownText.text = time.ToString();
    }
    // When countdown ended. You don't need to call StopCoroutine
    AfterCountdownFinished();
}
```

If your UIs have some sort animations that use `Time.deltaTime`to animate then you need to change it to use `Time.unscaledDeltaTime` instead. It's the same idea as `WaitForSeconds` and `WaitForSecondsRealtime`, one affected by `Time.timeScale` value while the other doesn't.

PS: I removed your `Update` function completely because you won't need it if you implement the way I did. And you don't need to call `StopCoroutine` anywhere since the countdown will automatically stop itself when ended

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I just tested it and I just added countDownUI.SetActive(true); at the beginning of LoseTime to bring up the UI. It works, but the countdown is very fast, not 3 seconds real time. It counts down to 0 in about 1 second :(

Comment: Oh I see. It seems that I can't create a delay and reuse it like `WaitForSeconds` I'll edit the answer

Comment: @BrendonSon I edited codes in the answer. This should fix the issue

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you so much :D You have no idea how many count down timers tutorials and cups of coffee to try and figure this out!! You are a lifesaver. Thank you for your time!